# React-redux. How to get updated store state on first application render

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, webpack-2

I am curious what is a good practice to render component and how to rerender it in order to get the updated store.

For example at the current moment the project has a store that listens for react-router and stores current location.

**Store**

```
export default (initialState = {slidesData}) => {

  const store = createStore(
    makeRootReducer(),
    initialState
  )

  store.asyncReducers = {}
  store.unsubscribeHistory = hashHistory.listen(updateLocation(store));

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      const reducers = require('./reducers').default
      store.dispatch(reducers(store.asyncReducers))
    })
  }

  return store
}
```

**Location reducer**

```
export const LOCATION_CHANGE = 'LOCATION_CHANGE';

const hash = '/#/',
      browser = '/';

// Action
export function locationChange (location = hash) {
  return {
    type: LOCATION_CHANGE,
    payload: location
  }
}


// Action creator
export const updateLocation = ({ dispatch }) => {
  return (nextLocation) => dispatch(locationChange(nextLocation))
}


// Reducer
const initialState = null;
export default function locationReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  return action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE
    ? action.payload
    : state
}
```

So on first application load the components that are subscribed to store receive `initialState = null` and when the first route change occurs the store updates and components now receive `"/current-route"`.

Can you please share your thoughts on what can be done in order to get `"current-route"` before the components that are subscribed to it will receive `null`.

Or how to handle the components render if they receive `null` and trigger their rerender in order to display updated store?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly but I display "Loading..." before connected components receive data from the store.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko, in this case it actually receives the data from store and it equals null, so it renders loading and it stays there forever.

Comment: Can't you just set initialState to the value you want to have when the application starts?

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko I can solve problem the other way, just curious if there is any other option

Comment: I see. I myself follow the reactjs topic on SO to learn about other ways in React :)

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko nice approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to get something into the state before any actions are dispatched (like a route change or something) is to put it in the default state object for a reducer.

i.e.  `const reducer = (state = <default state object>, action) => {...`

So in your case, instead of initializing with `null`, I would recommend grabbing the current route from the `window` object:

```
// Reducer
const initialState = window.location.pathname;
```